# mapping a java map to db table using orm

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, dictionary

I have a Map in my class.How can i map it to a db table using a orm(hibernate for example)

Map contains key value pairs

```
key1 val1
key2 val2
key3 val3
key4 val4
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what key and value actually represent. Using Hibernate look into either `org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements` (map primitives) or `org.hibernate.annotations.MapKey` (map entities).

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
    <map name="properties" table="MYENTITY_PROPERTY" lazy="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="MYENTITY_ID"/>
        <index column="PROPERTY_NAME" type="string"/>
        <element column="PROPERTY_VALUE" type="string"/>
    </map>
```